# Change value of Style color depending of value in php

Tags: php, html, echo

632/5000
I have a booking system written in PHP
There I would like to echo the values in different colors depending on the status of $ booking ['booking_status']

```
<span style="color:green"> <?php echo pjSanitize::html($booking['booking_status']); ?></span>
```

Where color green should change from green to red if booking_status is pending

I have tryed something like this but color dont change

```
<? Php
$ t = $ booking ['booking_status'];

if ($ t === 'pending')
{
    $ color = 'red'
}
```

then i try to echo

```
<span style = color: $ color "> <? php echo pjSanitize :: html ($ booking ['booking_status']);?> </ span>
```

But i dont get the value of $color

Comment: Why do you have all those spaces between `$` and the variable name, like `$ color`?

Comment: The above code would give you a bunch of syntax errors because of the spaces between `$` and the variable names. Is this code a rewrite instead of a copy/paste of your actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "echo" the same way you are using in the rest of your code

```
<span style = "color:<?php echo $color;?>">
    <?php echo pjSanitize::html($booking['booking_status']);?>
</span>
```